# How to check the contents of a LPTSTR string?

Tags: c++, c, windows, qt

I'm trying to understand why a segmentation fault (*SIGSEGV*) occurs during the execution of this piece of code. This error occurs when testing the condition specified in the `while` instruction, but it does not occur at the first iteration, but at the second iteration.

```
LPTSTR arrayStr[STR_COUNT];
LPTSTR inputStr;
LPTSTR str;

// calls a function from external library
// in order to set the inputStr string
set_input_str(param1, (char*)&inputStr, param3);

str = inputStr;
while( *str != '\0' )
{
    if( debug )
        printf("String[%d]: %s\n", i, (char*)str);

    arrayStr[i] = str;
    str = str + strlen((char*)str) + 1;

    i++;
}
```

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25618847/364056), I have done some research on the internet and found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx), so I tried to modify the above code, using this piece of code read in this article (see below). However, this change did not solve the problem.

```
for (LPTSTR pszz = pszzStart; *pszz; pszz += lstrlen(pszz) + 1) {
 ... do something with pszz ...
}
```

As assumed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25618847/364056), it seems that the code expects double null terminated arrays of string. Therefore, I wonder how I could check the contents of the `inputStr` string, in order to check if it actually contains only one null terminator char.

**NOTE:** the number of characters in the string printed from `printf` instruction is twice the value returned by the `lstrlen(str)` function call at the first iteration.

Comment: What do you think `str = str + strlen(str) + 1;` does?

Comment: Ok, the final `+ 1` goes out of bounds, but I do not know what is the goal of this piece of code.

Comment: The loop was probably written expecting a set of consecutive strings rather than a single string.

Comment: I think that it might help if you gave us a sight of the commented out *other instructions*. That might confirm (or otherwise) the hunch that @Harry and I have.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The other instructions do not change `str`.

Comment: That's not my point. Do they read a single character from `str`, or do they read up to the first null-terminator? I wish you would be able to reveal more info. If only you did that then I'm sure we could decipher it and we wouldn't need to use so much guesswork.

Comment: It's still quite disappointing that you won't reveal the information.

Comment: I explained in more detail my question, based also on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25618847/364056).

Comment: OK, it's just as Harry and I thought. Step 1 is to remove the casts. Let me guess that you added them to make the code compile. That should have set off alarm bells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, now that you've included the rest of the code it is clear that it is indeed meant to parse a set of consecutive strings.  The problem is that you're mixing narrow and wide string types.  All you need to do to fix it is change the variable definitions (and remove the casts):

```
char *arrayStr[STR_COUNT];
char *inputStr;
char *str;

// calls a function from external library
// in order to set the inputStr string
set_input_str(param1, &inputStr, param3);

str = inputStr;
while( *str != '\0' )
{
    if( debug )
        printf("String[%d]: %s\n", i, str);

    arrayStr[i] = str;
    str = str + strlen(str) + 1;

    i++;
}
```

Specifically, the issue was occurring on this line:

```
while( *str != '\0' )
```

since you hadn't cast `str` to `char *` the comparison was looking for a wide nul rather than a narrow nul.

Comment: +1 My guess is that the original code used TCHAR for no good reason, compiled for ANSI, and use strlen etc. Then the asker comes along, compiles the code with Unicode, finds it won't compile, casts away the errors, and pays the price for lying to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = str + strlen(str) + 1;
```

You go out of bounds, change to

```
str = str + 1;
```

or simply:

```
str++;
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not know what is the goal of this piece of code: seems that at each iteration we want to move to the end of the string, but I do not understand the reason...

Comment: It's called pointer arithmetic, take a look to [Chapter 10.2 Pointers and Arrays; Pointer Arithmetic](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html) of C-FAQ, at the end you have an example of a similar `strcpy` implementation.

Comment: @Alter Actually, this is not the case at all

Answer (score 1):

Of course you are inconsistently using `TSTR` and `strlen`, the latter assuming `TCHAR = char`

In any case, `strlen` returns the length of the string, which is the number of characters it contains not including the nul character.

Your arithmetic is out by one but you know you have to add one to the length of the string when you allocate the buffer.

Here however you are starting at position 0 and adding the length which means you are at position `len` which is the length of the string. Now the string runs from offset `0` to offset `len - 1` and offset `len` holds the null character. Offset `len + 1` is out of bounds.

Sometimes you might get away with reading it, if there is extra padding, but it is undefined behaviour and here you got a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like code that expects double null terminated arrays of strings. I suspect that you are passing a single null terminated string.

So you are using something like this:

```
const char* inputStr = "blah";
```

but the code expects two null terminators. Such as:

```
const char* inputStr = "blah\0";
```

or perhaps an input value with multiple strings:

```
const char* inputStr = "foo\0bar\0";
```

Note that these final two strings are indeed double null terminated. Although only one null terminator is written explicitly at the end of the string, the compiler adds another one implicitly.

---

Your question edit throws a new spanner in the works? The cast in

```
strlen((char*)str)
```

is massively dubious. If you need to cast then the cast must be wrong. One wonders what `LPTSTR` expands to for you. Presumably it expands to `wchar_t*` since you added that cast to make the code compile. And if so, then the cast does no good. You are lying to the compiler (`str` is not `char*`) and lying to the compiler never ends well.

Comment: So, how I could print individually each character in a `LPTSTR`?

Comment: How could I add an additional null terminator to the end of a LPTSTR?

Comment: How could you print each character? That sounds like a totally different question. And as for the next comment, I showed how to double null terminate in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the segmentation fault is already given by Alter's answer. However, I'd like to add that the usual style of parsing a C-style string is more elegant and less verbose

```
while (char ch = *str++)
{
    // other instructions
    // ...
}
```

The scope of `ch` is only within in the body of the loop.

**Aside:** Either tag the question as `C` or `C++` but not both, they're different languages.